# All Square Product Photos in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

In my WooCommerce store, I would like all of my product images to be square. I have tried to regenerate thumbnails but this does not work. The images just get cropped where I want to display the full image in my catalog, single product and thumbnail images.